# Do elevators ever reset in Assassin's Creed Brotherhood?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

Do the "elevators" in *Assassin's Creed Brotherhood* ever reset? From the way they are built they look pretty much like single-use objects but that would be kind of annoying since you usually spend lots of time in a town and are likely to go to the same place twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they do reset - they're only disabled for a short while after you use them.  Leaving the general area and returning tends to get them to reset.